# Invalid Template Argument for vector instantiation on Eclipse C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, vector

I have such a code in c++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

.....................
.....................

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> objects, fitting_objects;

    objects.push_back(new Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20)); // classic polymorphism spectacle

    // rectangle for the area containing the objects we're looking for
    Rectangle r(5, 5, 30, 30);

    for(auto const& object : objects)
        if(object.fitsIn(r))
            fitting_objects.push_back(object);

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why I get "invalid template argument" error. There are similar people who has experienced the same problem with me. I have implemented the same solution they had, but I couldn't go further.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Please quote the exact error message, and better prepare an [MCVE]

Comment: I have already stated the error on title: "Invalid Template Argument". That's it.

Comment: You forgot to `#include <memory>` for std::shared_ptr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::shared_ptr` constructor is explicit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr). You need to `push_back` a `shared_ptr` or use [`std::vector::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) instead

```
objects.push_back(std::make_shared<Rectangle>());
objects.emplace_back(new Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20)); // OK, careful if emplace_back throws, thanks @Simple
```

Minimal example that reproduces the issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct X{};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<X>> v;
    // v.push_back(new X); // does not compile
    v.push_back(std::shared_ptr<X>(new X)); // OK
    v.emplace_back(new X); // OK, careful if emplace_back throws, thanks @Simple
}
```

Comment: I can't change my code. Could you please tell me why I cannot use "vector" although I have defined it according to syntax rules?

Comment: When you push_back `new Object`, you try to construct a `shared_ptr` out of a raw pointer. Because the ctor of the latter is explicit, the compiler cannot convert `new Object` to `std::shared_ptr<Object>(new Object)`.

Comment: But the thing is, I have error on this line: std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> objects, fitting_objects;

Comment: Make sure you `#include <memory>` also.

Comment: I HAVE ERROR ON INCLUDING VECTOR. THIS DAMN ECLIPSE DOESN'T INCLUDE IT. THERE IS RED LINE ON VECTOR AND SHARED_PTR!

Comment: @yusuf Also, if you use C++98, leave a space between `> >` in the `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>>`

Comment: `objects.emplace_back(new Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20));` Noooooooooooo. This is very bad and can leak memory. Never `emplace_back` a smart pointer.

Comment: @Simple ?! Why?! Can you give an example or incorrect use case? [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb2081b301bed932).

Comment: @vsoftco what do you think happens if `emplace_back` can't allocate memory?

Comment: @Simple It throws, simple as that. Writing 100% exception safe code is hard, and probably well beyond the scope of this question. I edited the question anyway, thanks.

Comment: @Simple I am not sure however that you end up with a dangling pointer. `new` throws, so it doesn't allocate memory. It's not like `foo(new X, Y)`, where `Y` may throw and leave the memory allocated by `new X` dangling. I still have to look into the exception guarantees of std::emplace_back though.

Comment: @vsoftco `new Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20)` can allocate and yet `emplace_back` can fail afterwards. In this case you have a dangling pointer.